# Issues with displaying list using DataGridView in Windows Forms, .NET Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, .net-core

Code:

```cs
public MainMenu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var employeesList = DatabaseMethods.GetEmployees();
            var source = new BindingSource(employeesList, null);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
        }
```

```cs
public class DatabaseMethods
    {
        public static async Task<List<Employees>> GetEmployees()
        {
            await using var context = new NorthwindContext();
            var query = await context.Employees.ToListAsync();
            return query;
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image: Link to image]

How can i fix it? It seems that DataGridView should automatically display list in this window, but for me it appears to display whole list in one row, which just shows a bunch of references.

After a lot of searching thing like this works:

```cs
        private async void LoadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ICollection<Employees> list = await DatabaseMethods.GetEmployees();
            var listSource = new BindingList<Employees>(list.ToList());
            var source = new BindingSource(listSource, null);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
        }
```

But it requires adding button for loading the list. I wanted to fill list during initialization, but i would have to make async constructor, which seems to be impossible.

Edit

Ok i can just move this code to different function and call it in main. Problem solved.

Comment: Those column are complex objects and you need to return a string value for the complex object.

Comment: @jdweng i will try to think of something, it works fine when i create one new element of type Employee, but whole list gives this result.

Comment: The class is an object so casting from a known type to object will always work.  But cast from an object to a type you have to specify the type.